# Apache Tika for parsing only Office docs - Build exclusions

Tags: apache-tika

I would like to parse files to text/xml.

I only really need to parse Microsoft Office documents (specifically, Microsoft Word).

I currently include the entire `tika-parsers` dependency in my application.

Since this is heavy and includes a lot of things I don't need, is there a list of modules I can safely exclude if I'm only interested in parsing Office documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Tika version](https://github.com/apache/tika/tree/2.x) which splits the libraries into [modules](https://github.com/apache/tika/tree/2.x/tika-parser-modules) based on the types of files they parse.

While it seems that this version is no longer being updated, it can be used as a guide to which modules are necessary for which file type you're parsing.

For example, looking at the `pom.xml` of the `tika-parser-advanced-module`, you can see that it depends on `opennlp-tools`, but that the `tika-parser-office-module` does not. Therefore, if you're only interested in parsing office docs, you can exclude `opennlp-tools`.

In addition, looking at the `ivy:report` (for maven, the dependency tree) can help.

If anyone has any input on this, I'm still open to hearing suggestions/comments.